# Name of estimates in the Cox model?

Tags: estimation, maximum-likelihood, cox-model

The estimates of the regression parameters in the Cox model are based on the partial likelihood :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportional_hazards_model

Thus, strictly speaking, they are not exactly "Maximum Likelihood Estimators". How are they referred to instead? "Partial Maximum Likelihood Estimators"?

Comment: MPLE (maximum partial likelihood estimate). page 128 on https://www4.stat.ncsu.edu/~dzhang2/st745/chap6.pdf